# Generate gitlab ci artifact as native file type

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to attach the ipk that is crated by my build step to a release. But it always attaches it as a zip file.

Is there a way to create a link to direct download the ipk, instead of the ipk in a zip?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently there is no way to prevent creation of the zip archive, but you should be able find link to the unzipped file in the job artifact browsing screen:

```
https://gitlab.com/<group-name>/<project-name>/-/jobs/<job-id>/artifacts/browse
```

You can reach it by clicking on the `Browse` button on the job details page.

See also [this issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/37384).

Comment: Yep that did it for me! Thanks for that info.